# Is there a load balancer that will terminate a GRE tunnel?

Tags: linux, networking, load-balancing, gre

I have a network in which several site routers send portions of their traffic to an inspection device via  GRE tunnel.  I am beginning to exceed the capacity of the inspection device.

I could always stand up two inspection devices to divide and conquer but that does not really scale well.  Is there a type of load balancer that will terminate my GRE tunnels and then forward the traffic onto the inspection devices (with a balancing algorithm preferably hashed on inside GRE source IP)>

I'm used to load balancers that hold a VIP for say a web server then dole the traffic out to 1/n web servers behind it.  The client's think they are talking to a web server but they are talking to an LB.  I'm looking for the same concept with GRE tunnels.

Is this possible?

I can not post pictures but the topology is:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YbLAJ.jpg

Multiple site routers have their own pair of 169 addresses and tunnels.